# Pandas: Plot data against lagged variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I expect this to be a solution in pandas, but anything else using matplotlib or pyplot is also fine.

I have data `df` in group-year format, as in

```
                     y    x
year group                                                       
1950 1               5    2 
     2               4    3
1951 1               1    2
```

Now I would like to do a scatter plot: I would like to have one variable (X) on the x-axis, and the other one on the y-axis, and plot all data-combinations (x,y).

However, it is a bit more difficult: I actually need to have lagged X on the x-axis, say, X.L1 - that is, one year lagged. So in the given example, since I have data on group 1 for two years that follow each other, it would show a (y=1, x=2) data point on the scatter.

Importantly, by X.L1 I do *not* mean that it is the previous data we have on X, no matter how old is it. It needs to be specifically data on X (in the same group) that is one year older. If there is no data on that, the corresponding (y,) point should not be part of the scatter plot.

The whole concept of a scatter plot is given by the non-diagonal elements of [Example](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-plot-matrix).

Thanks!